# How can I change the font size of ticks of axes object in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, subplot

I have a figure I added subfigure to (inset). I have used:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
subA = fig.add_axes([0.4,0.14,0.2,0.2])
```

I now want to change the `xtick` font size of the subfigure. I tried some naive approach such as

```
subA.get_xaxis().get_xticks().set_fontsize(10)
```

without any luck.

How can I do this then?

Answer (score 50):

Use:

```
subA.tick_params(labelsize=6)
```

Comment: This is a better solution if you don't want to have to respecify the tick labels

Answer (score 24):

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.xticks([0.4,0.14,0.2,0.2], fontsize = 50) # work on current fig
plt.show()
```

the x/yticks has the same properties as [matplotlib.text](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text)

Comment: This is not working!

Comment: not working for me either

Comment: not working for me.