# Matplotlib xticks font size if string

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to change the font size of my x axis that happens to be strings and not numbers. I have changed other charts that have integers by using :

```
plt.xticks(size=10)
```

However, this dose not work for some of my graphs that have months in the place of integers. Keep in mind i am not using subplots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the fontsize either by using the the `fontsize` keyword argument or if you want to globally change it to every plot in your script by updating the `rcParams` as

```
import matplotlib 
matplotlib.rc('xtick', labelsize=20)
```

Also look at this answer: [How to change the font size on a matplotlib plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899980/how-to-change-the-font-size-on-a-matplotlib-plot)

Or here: [How can I change the font size of ticks of axes object in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139630/how-can-i-change-the-font-size-of-ticks-of-axes-object-in-matplotlib)