# Plotting a Bar Chart on matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I plot a horizontal bar chart with the values at the end of the bar, Something similar to [this](https://www.edrawsoft.com/images/chartstypes/bar-chart-sample-graph.png)

I tried this

```
plt.barh(inc.index,inc)
plt.yticks(inc.index)
plt.xticks(inc);
plt.xlabel("Order Count")
plt.ylabel("Date")
```

[Bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Gkym.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display the value of the bar on each bar with pyplot.barh()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228069/how-to-display-the-value-of-the-bar-on-each-bar-with-pyplot-barh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be found here:
[How to display the value of the bar on each bar with pyplot.barh()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228069/how-to-display-the-value-of-the-bar-on-each-bar-with-pyplot-barh)

Just add the for loop as cphlewis said:

```
for i, v in enumerate(inc):
    ax.text(v + 3, i + .25, str(v), color='blue', fontweight='bold')
plt.show()
```

Here is the code that I tried for your situation:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
inc = [12, 25, 50, 65, 40, 45]
index = ["2019-10-31", "2019-10-30", "2019-10-29", "2019-10-28", "2019-10-27", "2019-10-26"]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.barh(index,inc, color='black')
plt.yticks(index)
plt.xticks(inc);
plt.xlabel("Order Count")
plt.ylabel("Date")

# Set xticks
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, max(inc)+15, step=10))

# Loop for showing inc numbers in the end of bar
for i, v in enumerate(inc):
    ax.text(v + 1, i, str(v), color='black', fontweight='bold')
plt.show()
```

Plot looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much how can I also increase the size of the ticks and change the font

Comment: Ticksize can be found from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139630/how-can-i-change-the-font-size-of-ticks-of-axes-object-in-matplotlib?lq=1 => ```plt.tick_params(labelsize=15)``` and for font see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321670/how-to-change-fonts-in-matplotlib-python

Answer (score 0):

To generate a plot with values superimposed, run:

```
ax = inc.plot.barh(xticks=inc, xlim=(0, 40));
ax.set_xlabel('Order Count')
ax.set_ylabel('Date')
for p in ax.patches:
    w = p.get_width()
    ax.annotate(f' {w}', (w + 0.1, p.get_y() + 0.1))
```

Note that I set *xlim* with upper limit slightly above the
maximum *Order Count*, to provide the space for annotations.

For a subset of your data I got:

[image]

And one more impovement:

As I see, your data is a *Series* with a *DatetimeIndex*.

So if you want to have y label values as dates **only** (without
*00:00:00* for hours), convert the index to *string*:

```
inc.index = inc.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

like I did, generating my plot.